# illegal configuration the labelname outlet from the classname to the UILabel is invalid error in ios xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

i am beginner of iOS and i am trying to display some array objects on the label. the label is located on the table cell. when i am going to hookup label and label object in the class then trowing the above error plz assist me .

Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect your label to class, you must make a subclass of UITableViewCell and set the class of your cell to be this one. e.g. you have a cell in your storyboard, you must set the class of that cell (the custom class that you made) and then you can make the outlet..

You can also work with tags. In this case, you will not need outlets. You can get the label using tag. Let me know if it's still not clear or confusing

Another thing that you can do (if you only need label in your cell, then no need to make custom/prototype cell). You can simply do it using UITableViewCell and it has label in it. You can do this as follows (in Swift):

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
cell.textLabel!.text = "Your text"
```

Comment: Thank's ... working properly by changing superclass.

Comment: Hi Fayza, I need your help. I want to fetch google+ circle friend list using login to gmail A/C In objective c. i tried so much but unable to fetch. please help me . Thank You.

Comment: Hi @Bhimashankar, i've not worked with google+ so i'm not sure what's the issue you're facing.. may be if you can explain a little about the problem and the solutions you've tried. Best.

Comment: Hi Fayza, i got one tutorial in swift it is http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/ . but i want similar in objective c. it is possible in objective c? Thank You.

Comment: @Bhimashankar, anything (piece of code) that's in Swift can be translated to obj-c and vice versa. In case you need help, iOS community is here :)

Answer (score 0):

TO connect uilabel outlet you have to subclass UITableViewCell first. Then declare uilabel outlet in that class. Assign that class to your tableview cell in xib and then try to set outlet.